# Best way to get url(s) for a class based view?

Tags: django, django-views

I have in my urls.py

```
url(r'^foo/$', FooView.as_view(),  name='foo-view'),        
url(r'^bar1/$', BarView.as_view(),  name='bar-one-view'),
url(r'^bar2/$', BarView.as_view(),  name='bar-two-view'),
```

Now i want to know, which names are conneced to a CBV-Class (or function), so that i can do something like this:

```
how_to_do_this(BarView.as_view)
```

which should return ['bar-one-view', 'bar-two-view']

Comment: Could you please rephrase your question? I'm afraid it is not clear what you're referring to.

Comment: i edited the question: maybe that's more clear now?

Comment: Hmm... perhaps you could state what you are trying to do. I can't see why you'd want to do this. You have one view associated with two URLs. Perhaps you might want to have separate views that inherit from one view.

Comment: What i am trying to do is: Having the Class of the View, i want to know if (which) url-names are defined for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the way it works for me now. Maybe there is a better one?

A mixin to give the view function a custom decorator, that stores the module and class:

```
class SignatureMixin(object):
   @classmethod
   view_func = super(SignatureMixin, cls).as_view(**initkwargs)
      signature = "%s.%s" % (inspect.getmodule(cls).__name__, cls.__name__ )        
      view_func.__signature__  = signature
      return view_func
```

So when a CBV in app/dir/whatever/views.py has this mixin ...

```
class SomeView(SignatureMixin,View):
    ...
```

... than i can recurse over urls.urlpatterns for an entry where the callback has:

```
callback.__signature__ == 'app.dir.whatever.views.SomeView'
```

Answer (score 0):

My ansatz: the URLconf is usually defined using a variable like `urlpatterns`, which is a list of objects of class `RegexURLPattern`. One of the members of this class is a `callback` method. You will need to import `urlpatterns` into your script then iterate over all `RegexURLPattern` objects until you get a match to your callable (CBV or FBV) after which you can then check the `name` member (assuming it was defined in the URLconf). This should give you the name of the view.

But, as I said, I can't think of why you'd want to do this.;-)

Comment: There's a problem in the details: How do i compare the callback method with my CBV? I can't use callback.__name__ == some_class_name because different CBVs will have the same name. Like two IndexView classes, imported from two different modules.

Comment: By *modules* are you referring to *apps*?

Comment: No, modules are python files. In trivial cases that's two views.py in different apps, but that could also be two python files in one app. But as far as i've seen, that would not make a difference anyway.